# How to generate human-readable access codes?

Tags: php, laravel, token, laravel-5.4

I am building an online-and-mailout ballot system in PHP/Laravel that requires an access token that is to be typed in by a person at some point, either the actual user or an administrator. As such, I would assume that the token would have to be generated and not traceable back to the original user via database dumps.

What would be the best way to generate such a code? I have looked at Hashids, but unsure if that would be a suitable solution, unless it is fine to use the ballot creation timestamp in seconds as a second value to use along with the ballot ID.

Comment: If I understand the question I believe that you would want to use `password_encrypt()` along with `uniqid()`.You would add the `password_encrypt()`ed string that `uniqid()` generates in a database as the access code that the user/administrator would get, and when the user/administrator types it in you would use `password_verify()` to verify that it matches the field in the database.

Comment: @Alesana: That is a good idea, but the problem with `uniqid()` is that it is fairly lengthy. I doubt that the target users would want to peck away at 13 letters and numbers before marking their ballots online or the administrator(s) similarly when they potentially receive 30+ ballots that they have to enter in manually.

Comment: If you want a shorter id, you can do so with a low chance of collision (chance that two id's will be the same), however the chance of collision is still there. I would recommend using a hash function with the crc32b alogorithm to generate an 8 character code. For example, `hash('crc32b', uniqid());`

Comment: Note when I say to use `password_encrypt()` I actually meant `password_hash()`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Best and one of the fastest is:

```
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(int));
```

binary safe and cryptographically secure, but if You want get with length wanted, You must cut this and then You will get easer to hook token made only from 16 characters. If You want get human reliable string You must implement it by self and this is long way. I made something like this using cryptographically secure extensions [SafeToken](https://php10.000webhostapp.com).

Answer (score 0):

Create a random  byte array with a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) such as `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` and then [Base58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58) encode the result. This will give the shortest human usable character string for level of unique-ness.

Base58 a very human usable character set without easily confused characters. One example of this usage is Bitcoin.

Here is the character set:
123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz